# creating a new project in android studio 3.0 taking too long, and error in creating

Tags: android

I am a beginner in the field of android studio. Creating a new project takes a lot of time - 15 minuted. I tried to enable the "offline work" option , but after I did it - it is still too slow.

And in addition , when I creat a new project, I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Is your app the empty one or are there already sample GUI widgets?

Comment: @Darth Moon the empty one

Comment: Android studio already checked for updates?

Comment: @Darth Moon   yes it did

Comment: Close project and create new one. That helped me ...

Answer (score 0):

First of Upgrade your PC configuration.

And to avoid the error download the SDK file properly.